# Wrong output from Mathematica when evaluating a summation

Tags: summation

Consider the sum

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n-r-1}{n-r}$$

This sum is not zero because when $r=n$, the result is $\binom{-1}{0} = 1$. However, plugging this formula into [Wolfram Alpha does return zero](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+r%3D0%2Cn+binomial+%28n-r-1%2C+n-r%29). Why is this?

Comment: Provide the code of your formula  in _Mathematica_

Comment: I just used the online wepage of mathematica, I plugged sum r=0,n binomial (n-r-1, n-r)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is a very different beast from *Mathematica*. From your original question, you used the former, but called it the latter, so I corrected it. But once more: the two things are very different.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica has no problem with specific values of n until `n == 10^6`

```
Table[{n,
   Sum[
    Binomial[n - r - 1, n - r],
    {r, 0, n}]},
  {n, 999998, 10^6}] // Grid
```

[image]

As stated in the documentation for [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), `"If the range of a sum is finite, i is typically assigned a sequence of values, with f being evaluated for each one."` The problem apparently occurs with the switch from enumerating the sum to symbolically evaluating the sum.

Comment: However, this doesn't explain why Mathematica fails for a symbolic `n`. In the symbolic case, it is actually not sum that fails, because the problem is due to fact that `Binomial[n - r - 1, n - r]` evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, this is due to the fact that the indefinite sum is $0$:

```
Sum[Binomial[n - r - 1, n - r], r]
   0
```

One simple cure is to split off the "peculiar" term,

```
Sum[Binomial[n - r - 1, n - r], {r, 0, n - 1}] + Binomial[n - n - 1, n - n]
```

but an even better route is to [flip the binomial coefficient](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/17/02/04/0005/):

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers, 
         Simplify[Sum[(-1)^(n - r) Binomial[0, n - r], {r, 0, n}]]]
```